# The origin of "yogurt" __is/was__ from Turkish

Tags: time-reference

> The origin of "yorgurt" **is/was** from Turkish.

Which is correct between **is** and **was** in the above sentence?

I am very confused about this matter.
When only focused on the geography, I feel that stating the fact something is from somewhere doesn't necessarily need to express the time. But regarding the fact it happened in the past anyway, it feels somehow necessary to include time concept in the verb.

Comment: The word yoghurt [yorgurt] originated in Turkey. This would a more concise way to put this, but I realise it doesn't answer the thrust of your question.

Comment: @Livrecache Thank you for the answering. It is also helpful. If I may ask you a question, can I ask you whether the present tense form of your sentence "It originates in Turkey" is also valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is/was is acting on the word "origin" - while the origin of something is "in" the past, it is a current quality of the thing. Therefore "is" is the correct word to use here.

Another note - if you mean to say that the word yorgurt came from the Turkish language, you don't need the "from". Simply say "the origin of yorgurt is turkish".

Thought experiment - can the origin of something ever change? If it did, then maybe you'd use was. "We thought the origin of the pyramids **was** Europe, now we know it **is** Egypt"

Comment: Thank you for the kindness. :) Is "The origin of yorgurt is from Turkish" weird or wrong? Or do you mean it is just not the best one?

Comment: I don't know the technical language reason for why that sounds weird. I would say that it sounds weird because the origin actually is Turkish, the origin isn't something else that stemmed from the Turkish language. Probably not the best explanation but it's just an extra word. People would understand what you mean but it does sound a bit weird.

Comment: Thank you for the further answer. Now I have understood it through. Your help was great to me. Wish you a good luck. :)